# link not being changed

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a Google Fonts font display type of thing, where a user types a font name and display text and the text is displayed in the font he chose.
JS:

```
  $("#font, #display-text").keyup(function () {
      var fontFamily = $(this).val();
      var font = fontFamily.split(' ').join('+');
      var prefix = "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=";
      var fontName = prefix + font;
      var displayText = $("#display-text").val();
      $("#font-link").attr('href', fontName);
      $("#display").text(displayText).css('font-family', "'" + fontName + "'");

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Type the name of the font (in full):</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="font" id="font" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type your display text:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="display-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
<link id="font-link" rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

I know the font is received from the `fonts.googleapis.com`, but it is not displaying correctly.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/h48r2sbw/)

Comment: `<link>` tags go in the `<head>`, not in the `<body>`.

Comment: I don't think that is what's causing the problem. It's just there because jsfiddle doesn't like `head`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `fontName` is the `prefix` and the `font`. So if someone inputs `Slabo 27px` the font-family put in the css is: `fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px`, not `Slabo 27px`. Instead, give the css this:

```
 $("#font, #display-text").keyup(function () {
      var fontFamily = $(this).val();
      var font = fontFamily.split(' ').join('+');
      var prefix = "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=";
      var fontName = prefix + font;
      var displayText = $("#display-text").val();
      $("#font-link").attr('href', fontName);
      $("#display").text(displayText).css('font-family', "'" + fontFamily + "'");

  });
```

Notice the `fontName` in the `.css` is changed to `fontFamily`.